# Addition of two numbers in c

Tags: c

Is there any possibilities to read and add two or three different integers by using single variable ( int a ) in C language?

I didn't want to use array

Comment: Just use two variables, man

Comment: None that I can think of.

Comment: This question ia asked to me when I am attended the programming competition in my college

Comment: sounds funny kind of... are you reading this input from an  input stream or you have the values figured out already?

Comment: Seriously, if you want to add 4 8bit integer with a single 32bit integer, or 2 16bit integers with a single 32bit integer, you can use pointer casting and bitshift to do that

Comment: @LPs I am curious to know, How it is possible with single variable ? Can you explain with example ?

Comment: @Mohan I posted an answer

Comment: Semantically an array **is** a single variable ...

Comment: Or you `malloc` a struct to a single pointer which contains all data. Also just a single variable. Heck, who makes such constraints? A PIC12 programmer?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I'm getting you, but for example, if you want to add 2 16 bits integers with a single 32bit integer, you could do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t a;

    printf("Enter number 1: ");
    scanf("%hd", (uint16_t *)(&a));

    printf("Enter number 2: ");
    scanf("%hd", ((uint16_t *)(&a))+1);

    printf("%X\n", a);

    printf("Sum = %"PRIu32"\n", (uint32_t)(*(uint16_t *)(&a)) + *(((uint16_t *)(&a)) + 1));

    return 0;
}
```

The logic is to think about variable equals to arrays of bytes, and that's it.

This implementation still have problems that are well explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: Violating strict aliasing rule and depends on endianess.

Comment: @Olaf ...but it works.

Comment: @Olaf Edited and splitted. The avenger changes the DV

Comment: There is no DV! Please just add a note about the problems. "It works" is too often said about UB before the rocket explodes.

Comment: @LPs you are missing something in last line... printf("Sum = %d\n", (uint32_t)(*(uint16_t *)(&a)) + *(((uint16_t *)(&a)) + 1));

Comment: @Mohan Yes, you right. Thx. I edited.

Comment: After @Mohans comment: You use the wrong format specifier (for `signed int`), even **iff** `uint32_t` was `unsigned int`. For `stdint.h` use `inttypes.h` format macros, here that would be `PRIu32`.

Comment: @Olaf Good multi-platform catch. I edited.

Comment: @Olaf I now realize you wrote there is a problem with endianess. Where and why?

Comment: @LPs: Sorry, that was a mistake. You just use the uint32_t like an `uint16_t[2]` and do not shift. Anyway, that is a stupid constraint: forcing standard violation for - what? For not saving any memory & being less readable. Who makes such constraints? (this is a rhetorical questions, I well know there are enough id*ts in the word)

Answer (score 0):

No. Every time you you atribute a new value to the same variable it replaces the old one. If you don't want to use an array and it's a simple code to add numbers, just declare three variables and atribute each value to one of them.

Comment: Actually two variables are sufficient.

Comment: He said two or three, so...

Comment: "... add two or three different integer (**values**) by using single **variable**" (bold addition mine)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you would like this, but another way you can do this will be to accept inputs like you punch in calculators, and parse to int before applying the operations on them.

Something like this

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char buffer[256];
    char * pch;

    printf("input your numbers in this format ${number1}+${number2}...: ");
    fgets (buffer, 256, stdin);

    int sum = 0;
    pch = strtok (buffer, "+");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        sum += atoi (pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, "+");
    }
    printf("the sum is %\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

so, run it and input 2+2+2 and it does the calculation for you. thanks

Comment: There are too many variables in your code!

Comment: @Olaf that wasn't the problem... the problem was how to sum sets of inputs of number using one int variable instead of using array.

Comment: The question as given states different. If you have more information than given here, you should include in your answer.

Comment: @Olaf I considered conditions where the user might want more than 3 number inputs, let's say 20. how would you solve it using the approach of the first answer? that was what i got into consideration before doing this. and i stated clearly, that this might be another approach